# Wordpress front page image resize

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to resize an image on the front page of a website I've put together using Wordpress and Cyberchimps responsive theme.

Cyberchimps support suggested using this CSS to resize the image:

```
#featured #featured-content{
width:100%;
}

#featured wp-caption{
width:100%;
}

#featured .wp-caption img {
width: 100%;
}
```

However, on update the image is the same size. This isn't because of the actual image size used. Anyone got any experience with this theme?

Comment: Could you provide the html containing the image you are trying to resize

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy required templates/styles/scripts to your Child Theme root folder and there customize them.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

If so, update won't make any changes to your customization